# How can I get the win ratio of a value in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables on my database: one called 'LEAGUES' and another called 'MATCHES'. I want to obtain the winrate of each league depending on the favorable result of the matches related to those leagues.

The structure of the tables:

```
#######################  ###########################
#   TABLE LEAGUES     #  #       TABLE MATCHES     #
#######################  ########################### 
+----------+----------+  +-------------------------+ 
|    ID    |   name   |  |ID|match|League_id|Result|
+----------+----------+  +--+-----+---------+------+
|     1    |   aaa    |  |1 |xxxxx|    1    |  W   |
|     2    |   bbb    |  |2 |xxxxx|    1    |  L   |
|     3    |   ccc    |  |3 |xxxxx|    2    |  W   |
|     4    |   ddd    |  |4 |xxxxx|    3    |  W   |
+----------+----------+  |5 |xxxxx|    3    |  L   |
                         |6 |xxxxx|    3    |  W   |
                         +--+-----+---------+------+
```

The result i want:

```
#######################
#       RESULT        #
#######################
+----------+----------+  
|league.id | Winrate  | 
+----------+----------+
|     1    |   50%    |
|     2    |   100%   |
|     3    |   66%    | 
+----------+----------+
```

I tried the following code but it is not working because the subquery returns more than one value:

```
SELECT leagues.id, COUNT(leagues.id)*100/(SELECT COUNT(leagues.id) 
                              FROM leagues,matches WHERE 
                              leagues.id=matches.League_id 
                              GROUP BY leagues.id) as winrate 
FROM leagues,matches
WHERE leagues.id=matches.League_id and matches.result like 'W'
GROUP BY leagues.id
```

Is there another way to obtain these results? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip: don’t format numbers into percentages in SQL. Instead just return the raw ratio. It’s because formatting data for consumption by humans happens in the “view” layer of your application (not to be confused with a SQL `VIEW`).

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: (Erm, 27, I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT m.League_id,
       AVG( m.result = 'W' ) as winrate
FROM matches m
GROUP BY m.League_id;
```

Notes:

- You don't need the `leagues` table, because the field you need is in `matches`.
- Learn proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax (although it is not necessary for this query).
- MySQL treats booleans as numbers in a numeric context, with 1 for true and 0 for false, so `AVG( <boolean expression> )` returns the ratio of true values.  Pretty nifty.
- Although they do pretty much the same thing, `=` is more commonly used for equality comparisons as opposed to `like`.

Comment: Neat trick with the `AVG` function there! Do other DBMS do that?

Comment: @Dai . . . In general, they require a `case` expression:  `AVG( CASE WHEN m.result = 'W' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)`.